# Keep view controller code running after view controller get popped

Tags: swift, chat, xmppframework, image-upload

I am implementing chat functionality with the help of XMPP and chat is working fine. Now i am working on image uploading and for that i upload image to s3 bucket and after uploading image to s3 i send s3 image url as message to other user using xmpp method. This is also working fine but problem is it is only working if i stay on same screen i.e chat screen when image is uploading. So if my image is still uploading and i pop from view controller it gets deallocated and my completion handler not get called after uploading image to s3 and because of that my sendMessage method is also not get called. So how can i achieve this. how can i send my messages and get completion handler called even if i am on different screen while image is uploading.

This is my code for picking image and upload image

```
@IBAction func didPressMedia(_ sender: Any) {
        ImagePickerManager().pickImage(self) { \[weak self\] pickedImage in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        let compressedImage = pickedImage.resizedImage(newSize: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120))
        
        let messageId = XMPPHelper.shared.xmppStream.generateUUID

        let chat = ChatListModel()
        chat.roomId = ""
        chat.message = ""
        chat.messageId = messageId
        chat.time = String(Date().currentTimeMillis())
        chat.to = self.viewModel.otherUser
        chat.from = self.viewModel.myJid ?? ""
        chat.type = "chat/image"
        chat.imageLocalPath = messageId
        chat.msgDeliveryStatus = MsgDeliveryStatus.sending.rawValue
        chat.isSeenSync = true
        chat.isUploading = "pending"
        
        self.viewModel.setChatDataInRealm(item: chat, isAfterPickingImage: true)

        //This is completion handler which get called after image upload to s3.
        self.viewModel.didImageUploaded = { [weak self] isImgUploaded , imgUrl, imgMessageId in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if isImgUploaded {
                print("success uploading image")
                self.viewModel.sendMessage(message: imgUrl, isImage: true, messageId: imgMessageId). // send image url as message to other user

            }else{
                print("error uploading image")
                self.viewModel.updateRealmAfterImageUpload(uploadStatus: "failed", uploadedUrl: "", messsageId: imgMessageId)
            }
        }

        self.viewModel.uploadImage(localPath: "\(Helper.shared.getDocumentDirectoryPath(filename: messageId)).png" ,image: compressedImage, messageId: messageId)
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest creating a `Singleton class` to handle the logic for `didImageUploaded`, `sendMessage,` and other related methods in the chat screen. You can then create a separate closure that can be used for the `ViewController/ViewModel`

Comment: @RashidLatif i have put didImageUploaded, sendMessage code in singelton class and calling this from viewcontroller by passing viewModel object as parameter like this  S3UploadManager.shared.uploadImage(viewModel: self.viewModel) and it is working for me but i am note sure if this is correct way as viewModel object will not get deallocated even if i popped from view controller. so can you please tell me is there any better way for doing this or is this correct way ?

Comment: You don't need to include the ViewModel object in the Singleton class. Instead, you can place methods such as `didImageUploaded`, `sendMessage`, and `updateRealmAfterImageUpload` in the Singleton. Let me try an example for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
class ChatManager {
    
    static let shared = ChatManager()
    private init() {}
    
    
    func uploadImage(localPath: String, image: UIImage, messageId: String, didImageUploaded: @escaping (Bool, String?, String?) -> Void) {
        
        // Code to upload image to server...
        //Once image is uploaded you can continue the logic here. and after that call the closure `didImageUploaded`
        if isImgUploaded {
            print("success uploading image")
            self.sendMessage(message: imgUrl, isImage: true, messageId: imgMessageId) // send image url as message to other user
            
        }else{
            print("error uploading image")
            self.updateRealmAfterImageUpload(uploadStatus: "failed", uploadedUrl: "", messsageId: imgMessageId)
        }
        
        // Call didImageUploaded closure after image upload if needed.
        didImageUploaded(true, "imageUrl", "messageId")
        
    }
    
    func sendMessage(message: String, isImage: Bool, messageId: String) {
        // Code to send message to other user
    }
    
    func updateRealmAfterImageUpload(uploadStatus: String, uploadedUrl: String, messageId: String) {
        // Code to update Realm database after image upload
    }
}
```

**How to call**

```
ChatManager.shared.uploadImage(localPath: "\(Helper.shared.getDocumentDirectoryPath(filename: messageId)).png", image: compressedImage, messageId: messageId) { [weak self] isImgUploaded, imgUrl, imgMessageId in
    //Refresh views if needed.
 }
```

Comment: okay @RashidLatif i will try to impliment this way. i think this is better way to handle my scenario. Thanks for the example.